# Sails.js policy removed but need when loading the application

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, policy

I created a policy called "flash" that I deleted (because I don't need it anymore) in my Sails.js application.
But when I load the application I get the following error :

```
error: Unknown policy, "flash", referenced in `config.policies`.
error: Are you sure that policy exists?
error: It would be located at: `/Users/Pierre/Documents/ING5/PFE/Node/InfomelessSite/api/policies/flash.js`
```

In **policies.js** :

```
module.exports.policies = {

  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * Default policy for all controllers and actions (`true` allows public     *
  * access)                                                                  *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/

  //'*': false

  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * Here's an example of mapping some policies to run before a controller    *
  * and its actions                                                          *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/
    // RabbitController: {

        // Apply the `false` policy as the default for all of RabbitController's actions
        // (`false` prevents all access, which ensures that nothing bad happens to our rabbits)
        // '*': false,

        // For the action `nurture`, apply the 'isRabbitMother' policy
        // (this overrides `false` above)
        // nurture  : 'isRabbitMother',

        // Apply the `isNiceToAnimals` AND `hasRabbitFood` policies
        // before letting any users feed our rabbits
        // feed : ['isNiceToAnimals', 'hasRabbitFood']
    // }
};
```

How is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be checking policies.js at
`REPO_DIR/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-generate/node_modules/sails-generate-backend/templates/config/policies.js`

You need to check this file: `REPO_DIR/config/policies.js` and remove any reference to `flash` policy there.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm looking at the right path : /Users/Pierre/Documents/ING5/PFE/Node/InfomelessSails/config/policies.js

Comment: Have you also tried `grunt clean`, re-lifting sails, searching 'flash' in whole app directory?